# intermittent connectivity between Google Cloud SQL server and Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm seeing intermittent connection issues between my Google Cloud SQL instance and my Google Compute Engine instance via php.

The connection between the two either fails or is just extremely slow.

Is there an issue with Cloud SQL / compute engine connectivity that hasn't been reported on the Status page?

Comment: Can you please confirm the instance was in europe-west-1b? Feel free to post project_id and vmname as a comment.

Comment: Hi Riccardo.

It was, after cloning the VM to a different zone there wasn't an issue so support managed to track it down to an issue with a network node that wasn't picked up by internal monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a connectivity issue for VMs in `europe-west-1b` zone that was resolved as of 2015-04-08 06:30 US/Pacific.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working fine, but a few hours ago it was quite unstable, and 3 of the 5 requests failed.

Comment: After paying for technical support as I was getting desperate they tracked it down to an issue with a network node dropping packets. However as it only affected a minority of VM's they didn't post it to the system status page.